# Fortify SSC Statefulset webapp pod unable to connect to statefulset fortify-msql pod in kubernetes cluster when Istio Is enabled

Tags: mysql, devops, kubernetes-helm, istio, fortify

I am deploying MicroFocus Fortify SSC in my kubernetes cluster via a helm chart. The helm chart I am using can be found here https://repo1.dso.mil/big-bang/apps/third-party/fortify/-/tree/0.0.9-bb.2/. I am using kubernetes distribution of RKE2 v1.23.5+rke2r1, which uses containerd as a CRI.  It deploys two different statefulsets in the fortify namespace. One is called fortify-fortify-ssc-webapp and fortify-mysql for it's database. Whenever I deploy it without the `istio-injection: enabled` label using it's default suggested configmap.yaml the pods come up fine and the webapp pod is able to connect to it's mysql db pod. However, whenever I enable istio sidecars in the fortify namespace by adding the `istio-injection: enabled` label the fortify-fortify-ssc-webapp-0 pod gets stuck in the init phase and can't seem to get past any of it's init-containers.

When Describing the fortify-fortify-ssc-webapp-0 pod the last messages look like this:

```
  Normal  Scheduled               4m45s  default-scheduler        Successfully assigned fortify/fortify-fortify-ssc-webapp-0 to <IP address>
  Normal  SuccessfulAttachVolume  4m43s  attachdetach-controller  AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-ID"
  Normal  Pulled                  4m39s  kubelet                  Container image "registry1.dso.mil/ironbank/bitnami/mysql8:8.0.29-debian-10-r37" already present on machine
  Normal  Created                 4m38s  kubelet                  Created container seed-data-loader
  Normal  Started                 4m38s  kubelet                  Started container seed-data-loader
  Normal  Killing                 10s    kubelet                  Stopping container seed-data-loader
```

And stops there. It seems like it's not able to get past the seed-data-loader container. The seed-data-loader init-container contains the following:

```
/bin/bash
      -ecv
      while ! mysqladmin ping -h $DBHOST --silent; do
        sleep 10
      done
      mysql -h $DBHOST -u $DBROOTUSER -p$DBROOTPASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS fortify CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin"
```

The logs of the fortify-mysql-0 pod give me this error:

```
seed-data-loader mysqladmin: connect to server at 'fortify-mysql' failed
seed-data-loader error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'fortify-mysql:3306' (111)'
seed-data-loader Check that mysqld is running on fortify-mysql and that the port is 3306.
seed-data-loader You can check this by doing 'telnet fortify-mysql 3306'
```

My configmap.yaml comes from the default fortify/chart/values.yaml in the helm chart and looks like this:

```
# configurable parameters
storage:
  volume: 5Gi

databaseSecret:
  name: db-credentials-mysql
  useRoot: true # Use root credentials to create database if required

istio:
  enabled: true
  gateways:
    - istio-system/main

key_store_password: dsoppassword
key_store_cert_password : dsoppassword
fortify_autoconfig: |
  appProperties:
    host.validation: false
    searchIndex.location: '/fortify/ssc/index'
  datasourceProperties:
    jdbc.url: "jdbc:mysql://fortify-mysql:3306/fortify?useSSL=false&connectionCollation=<collation>&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&max_allowed_packet=1073741824&sql_mode=TRADITIONAL"
    db.driver.class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    db.username: root
    db.password: root
    db.dialect: com.fortify.manager.util.hibernate.MySQLDialect
    db.like.specialCharacters: '%_\\'
  dbMigrationProperties:
    migration.enabled: true


fortify_license: |
  <License>

podAnnotations:
  traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: "5701,8888,8081,3306,5432"
  traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "5701,8888,8081,8091,3306,5432"
```

**Things that I've tried to solve this issue:**

added a network policy to try to allow traffic between the pods over port 3306.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-mysql
  namespace: fortify
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: fortify
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
```

Added podAnnotations to the configmap.yaml to try to open those ports up.

```
podAnnotations:
  traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeOutboundPorts: "5701,8888,8081,3306,5432"
  traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "5701,8888,8081,8091,3306,5432"
```

Applied sidecar.yaml in an attempt to allow traffic

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: fortify
spec:
  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: ALLOW_ANY

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: ALLOW_ANY
```

created service attempting to fix it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-test
  namespace: fortify
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3306
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fortify
```

Created destinationrules in attempt to fix it.

```
apiVersion: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
kind: "DestinationRule"
metadata:
  name: "istio-client-mtls"
  namespace: "fortify"
spec:
  host: "*.svc.cluster.local"
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck on this error for some time now.